# Problem with connecting heroku db and flask app

Tags: database, flask, heroku

I am trying to connect my flask app to Heroku database. I tried a million thinks and aways getting the same error message :
[image: error mesage]

From the terminal, I am logging in to my app DB and getting the following message:

> You are connected to database "dclhb9ntogjjr" as user "ikkcwdbfbqzfiw"
>   on host "ec2-54-195-247-108.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (address
>   "54.195.247.108") at port "5432". SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2,
>   cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)

I tried to set variable  DATABASE_URL=" ??????",but I am not sure how to get my DB URL from Heroku.
If you have any ideas how to fix that please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you Heroku Database is setup correctly.

Next you SHOULDN'T set the value of DATABASE_URL

The DATABASE_URL is a environment variable. To acces it you need this code

```
import os
database_url=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happens even after I add it.

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
database_url=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
database_url=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Project 1: TODO"
```